# Set cookie on the click of hyperlink and open page in safari (iOS9.3)

Tags: javascript, safari, ios9.3

I want to open a page in safari on the click of a link in iOS 9.3
Anchor tag works well for this:

```
<a id="newResourceLink" target="_blank" href="URL">Open link in safari</a>
```

but on adding following javascript, the page starts opening up in the application itself, not in safari.

```
$('a#newResourceLink').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.cookie("ASESSIONID", "value", { path: '/abc' });
            window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
});
```

I have tried following substitutes for window.open but none works:
1. location.href = $(this).attr('href'); 
2. doucment.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); 
3. window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you just don't stop propagation by deleting `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: If I don't stop event propagation then cookie is not set and the page opens in safari.